# R ggplot and how to place a reference `geom_line` with CIs behind 2 factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a minimal example of plotting two-factor effects with `ggplot`:

```
dat = data.frame(
    Factor1 = c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3), rep('C', 3)),
    Factor2 = rep(c('X', 'Y', 'Z'), 3),
    Y = c(0.15, 0.35, 0.25, 0.16, 0.34, 0.27, 0.12, 0.37, 0.23),
    CI = c(0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.04),
    stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
dat$lo95 = dat$Y - dat$CI
dat$hi95 = dat$Y + dat$CI

p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Factor1, y=Y, colour=Factor2)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.0,0.8)) +
    geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9), size=2.5, stat='identity') +
    geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=.25, size=.5,
        aes(ymin=lo95, ymax=hi95)) +
    scale_x_discrete(name='Factor 1') +
    scale_y_continuous(name='Pr') +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('#e41a1c', '#4daf4a', '#377eb8')) +
    labs(colour='Factor 2:') +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank())
p1
```

I wonder how could I place something like a reference line with confidence intervals; of course, "behind" the points and bars (preferably greyed CIs), like the one on the picture:

[image]

Comment: If you add something like `+ geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5), colour = c("grey", "black", "grey"))` before the `geom_point()` line; doesn't that work?

Comment: It does!  And how can I turn those grey lines into an area, like proper confidence intervals (typically grey stripe in ggplot)? Thanks @teunbrand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get pretty far with an annotated ribbon and a `geom_hline()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat = data.frame(
  Factor1 = c(rep('A', 3), rep('B', 3), rep('C', 3)),
  Factor2 = rep(c('X', 'Y', 'Z'), 3),
  Y = c(0.15, 0.35, 0.25, 0.16, 0.34, 0.27, 0.12, 0.37, 0.23),
  CI = c(0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.04),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
dat$lo95 = dat$Y - dat$CI
dat$hi95 = dat$Y + dat$CI

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Factor1, y=Y, colour=Factor2)) +
  annotate("ribbon", ymin = 0.3, ymax = 0.5, x = c(-Inf, Inf),
           fill = "grey90") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.4) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.0,0.8)) +
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9), size=2.5, stat='identity') +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=.25, size=.5,
                aes(ymin=lo95, ymax=hi95)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name='Factor 1') +
  scale_y_continuous(name='Pr') +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('#e41a1c', '#4daf4a', '#377eb8')) +
  labs(colour='Factor 2:') +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Or if you wanted a dotted line, you can go with:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Factor1, y=Y, colour=Factor2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.5), 
             colour = c("grey", "black", "grey"),
             linetype = c(2,1,2)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.0,0.8)) +
  {rest of code}
```